# How to cluster a set of images?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I have a set of images (`imgset`) as

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Clearly, the classification list should be

```
{1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,5,5,5,6,6,6}
```

One approach that I have tried is binarizing the images (using `Binarize`) followed by computing the `DiceDissimilarity` between any two images. However, I don't find any fixed threshold value to group the images.

How efficiently can these images be classified?

Comment: @AntonAntonov Title edited. Thanks.

Comment: The `"Spectral"` method for `FindClusters` does a good job *IF* you specify the number of clusters which, I realize, is a big if... `FindClusters[imgs, 6, Method -> "Spectral"]`.

Comment: @MarcoB I tried that first, but I thought although the results are kind of good, that approach does not allow much further tweaking. (Someone who knows image processing better than me might disagree...)

Answer (score 6):

Here is the result with a somewhat too ad-hoc clustering:

[image]

May be with some tweaking the code below can produce more desired results. But please observe the obtained clusters. Although, they are not exactly as the ones mentioned in the question the found clusters "make lots of sense."

### Get the images

```
imgLinks = 
 Flatten[StringCases[
   Import["https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174223/34008", 
    "Hyperlinks"], __ ~~ "imgur" ~~ __]]

imgs = Import /@ Take[imgLinks,36]
```

### First try

```
ColumnForm[FindClusters[imgs, 6, Method -> "Spectral"]]
```

[image]

### Clustering code

In order to get better results with further tweaking I would use a vector representation. `FeatureExtract` (coupled with transformations like `GaussianFilter` etc.) can be used, but I got better results by just taking the image data.

```
vecsImgs = Flatten /@ Map[ImageData, imgs];
Tally[Dimensions /@ vecsImgs]

(* {{{5625}, 36}} *)

cls = 
 FindClusters[vecsImgs -> Range[Length[vecsImgs]], 6, 
  DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance]

(* {{1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 25, 27}, {4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14,
   15, 19, 20, 21, 26}, {16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24}, {28, 29, 30, 34, 35,
   36}, {31, 32, 33}} *)

ColumnForm[imgs[[#]] & /@ cls]
```